# Add class to an input on focus

Tags: html

I'm looking for some help, I have this input

```
<div class="input-field section scrollspy col s12 m12 l6">
     <i class="material-icons prefix">today</i>
     <input name="INICIO" id="fechaInicio" type="text" class="datepicker" minlength=10 placeholder="##-##-####" pattern="[0-9-]{10}"> 
     <label for="fechaInicio" data-error="Incorrecto" data-success="Correcto" class="active">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
</div>
```

And I want to add the class "valid" to it, when it is focused, but I don't know too much about Jquery, Can anyone please help me to solve my little problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following jQuery. It just uses the `focusin()` (equivalent to `onfocus`) and `focusout()` (equivalent to `onblur`) event handlers to add and remove classes (`addClass()` and `removeClass()`, respectively).

**EDIT** Updated to show proper usage of jQuery as well.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var input = $("input[name=INICIO]");
    input.focusin(function() {
        $(this).addClass("valid");
    });
    input.focusout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("valid");
    });
</script>
```

See [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ynb0cqe/) on JSFiddle.net.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, but I'm still on the moon, where do I paste that code? where do I call it? please, don't get mad, I'm just staring to know JQuery :(

Comment: jQuery is JS, so you can paste it in a `<script>` tag after including the jQuery library file. I'll add it in a moment, don't worry.

Comment: @ErickKirei I'm glad I did!